# dash line between rows in a table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Why there is no dash-line between the rows s12 and s1n like between the columns s22 and s2m? Normally there should be one. What I did wrong? Thank you!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik

\usepackage{multirow,array} 
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c|}} % Anzahl Spalten
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spieler $2$} \\ \cline{3-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & $s_{21}$  & $s_{22}$ & $\hspace{0.3in}$ & $s_{2m}$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\multirow{4}*{Spieler $1$} 
& $s_{11}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
& $s_{12}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
& $s_{1n}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

[image]

You can do that with `\multicolumn{1}{c:}{}` to create row with vertical dashed line as separator.

To control gap between dash segments you can modify the length `\dashlinegap` the default is 4pt

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\dashlinegap=2pt

\begin{document}


\begin{table}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c|}}

\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spieler $2$} \\ \cline{3-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}

\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & $s_{21}$  & $s_{22}$ & $\hspace{0.3in}$ & $s_{2m}$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}

\multirow{4}*{Spieler $1$} 

& $s_{11}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}

& $s_{12}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}

\multicolumn{1}{c:}{\vbox to 1cm{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}

& $s_{1n}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5}

\cline{6-6}

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to make bigger the space between the rows s12 and s1n, so you can see the dash line better? I hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: I have updated my answer, just insert `\vbox to 1cm{}` as argument of `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 6):

See the screenshot please -- is this what you want to achieve?

`\cline{...} \cdashline{...} \cline{...}` will print a solid line | dashed line | solid line. If the line should be dashed from column 2 to 6 then use `\cdashline{2-6}` and drop the `\cline{...}` statements.

The empty line can be achieved easier with `\multicolumn{6}{c}{} \tabularnewline`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik

\usepackage{multirow,array} 
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c|}} % Anzahl Spalten
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spieler $2$} \\ \cline{3-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & $s_{21}$  & $s_{22}$ & $\hspace{0.3in}$ & $s_{2m}$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
   \multirow{4}*{Spieler $1$} 
   & $s_{11}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
   & $s_{12}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ 
   \cdashline{2-6}%
   \multicolumn{6}{c}{} \tabularnewline
   \cdashline{2-6} 
   & $s_{1n}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & ${}$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-4} \cdashline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am sorry for the bad description. I meant it like salim bou understood it. Sorry! But thank you anyway!!